# Including a JSP page with Icefaces/Facelets

Tags: jsp, jsf, facelets

I have a requirement to allow a user to embed JSP pages into my website...I'm using IceFaces/Facelets to do the navigation menus etc. and would like to include a JSP page using ui:include

Is there anyway of doing this (given that the JSP is not valid XML).

Thanks.